# LINQ debug time code change... is it possible in vs2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linq, edit-and-continue

is there any ways to accomplish this? it is really annoying having to restart every time.

Comment: If you're using the function chaining version of linq instead of the `from ... where ... select ...` version, try declaring the delegates as proper functions and referring to them by name so the compiler doesn't have to auto-generate them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not possible.  C# does not allow ENC anywhere in a method which contains a LINQ expression.  VB.Net allows you to edit within the same method as a LINQ expression as long as you don't actually edit the structure of the LINQ query.